# Variable SKU not showing on Single Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some problems displaying the SKU for variations, I modified the Single Product Page to display the Variations as a List, this is the Code I used (functions of the the Theme, tried with a Standard Theme, no change)

```html
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
  global $product, $post;
  $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
  foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
  ?>
  <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>"method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
   <?php
   if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
    <?php
    }
   }
   ?>
   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <b><?php echo implode('/', $value['attributes']);?></b>
      </td>
      <td>
       <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
 <?php
  do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );
  woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
   'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
   'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
   'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
  ) );
  do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
 ?>
 <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
 <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" /></div>
                                  <?php 
global $product;
?>
<div class>



    <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) ) : ?>


        <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'Artikelnummer: ', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>


  <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                            
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </form>
  <?php
  }
}
```

The only thing not working is getting the SKU of the Variation, instead it gets the SKU of the Product itself or nothing at all (this is the case with the code below, any hint/help would be appreciated. I also tried implent this [Variable Product Sku not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844357/variable-product-sku-not-working) 
but it didn't work either

Thanks in Advance (I hade trouble with getting all the coe to display in the code window so I have to use the snippet function, appologies for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was a bit hard to read but try using get_post_meta with the variation post id.

```
$variation_sku = get_post_meta( $value['variation_id'] , '_sku', TRUE );
```

See if that works.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm! Added it to the code and the SKU's showed up! Thank you very much indeed!